# How to call attributes of a database record in a Shopware 5 form

Tags: vue.js, symfony, shopware

I'm not familiar with Symfony or VueJS. I have an id of a table in a Shopware 5 form, how can I access the attributes of that record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Shopware5 or Shopware6?

- Shopware 5 uses Smarty in the storefront and ExtJS in Admin.
- Shopware 6 is build with Twig and VueJs.

If you want to access data from the database I'd recommend doing this in PHP and use the Repository of the Entity.

If you need the data in a specific view you could use a subscriber ([explained here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It's shopware 5. Is it absolutely not possible, to use VueJS in the Backend of shopware 5?

Comment: It might be possible by adding the needed libraries to your views. But I wouldn't recommend it!

If you don't want to take a dive into ExtJS you could use the [Lightweight modules](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/lightweight-backend-modules/).

Comment: Lightweight modules is an awesome tip! Thank you!